# Form submit but staying on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Ok, I know there are many similar subjects, I' ve read them but still I don't know how to solve the problem.

I have some simply form and code like this one:

```
$('#landing-form').submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
                    type: $(this).attr('method'),
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(html) {
                        alert('ok');
                    }
                });
                return false; 
            });
```

I'm trying to post my data but nothing is happening.
Url address isn't standard php file but it's integrated with zoho. Maybe there's a clue. I really don't know.

Comment: and the problem is ?

Comment: Well what do you expect it to do? You are submitting via ajax and you are prevent the default action (i.e. submit and reload/navigate)

Comment: you're not redirecting it to next page. how it is supposed to be redirected then ?

Comment: Remove the `return false` .The will prevent the `form.submit` default action

Comment: you aren't handling the error condition. Maybe there's an error. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ shows you how to write the "error" callback as an option. Also, you should check your browser's network tab and console to watch what is happening. Verify the request is actually firing, and then see what the response is. "Nothing's happening" is very unlikely (unless you've got no form element with the id "landing-form" on the page). Something will be happening, but it might not be what you think it is.

Comment: @prasad `event.preventDefault()` is already stopping this. The `return false;` is superfluous due to this. But preventing the form's default action is desirable, otherwise a postback will occur and the ajax will be pointless.

Comment: To sum up: I don' t want to go the next page, that' s why I' m using preventDefault(); I want to send data from this form, stay on the page and make form invisible and display some text ('Thanks for your time' or something like that).

Comment: check the data you are sending, in my experience, jQuery swallow exceptions for failed payload serializations on ajax calls

Comment: Ok. Thanks everyone for answers.

Comment: @Adrian did you fix it, then?

Comment: @ADyson As I remember.., yes. Thanks for all!